# How to keep different animation durations for two variables in the same animation

Tags: graphics3d, animation

I have a list of figures and strings to plot in a movie where each frame is slightly different from the previous one. I achieved that with the following code, where the `g[i]` are graphical elements (`Point`s and `Line`s), and the `S[i]` are strings (timestamps). I used `Animate` because it authomatically resets a frame's position in case the user would rotate it.

```
    Animate[Labeled[
  Graphics3D[g[[i]], 
   ViewPoint -> Front, 
   ImageSize -> Full], s[[i]], Top], {i, 1, 81, 1},  
 AnimationRunning -> False, DefaultDuration -> 20, 
 PreserveImageOptions -> False]
```

Now, I wish to make the plot rotate back and forth as the movie goes on. I used the following code:

```
Animate[Labeled[
  Graphics3D[g[[i]], 
   ViewPoint -> {Sin[t], -2.4 + Sin[t]/2, 2*Sin[t]}, 
   ImageSize -> Full], s[[i]], Top], {i, 1, 81, 1}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False, DefaultDuration -> 20, 
 PreserveImageOptions -> False]
```

And the plot looks like this:
[image: Frame of the plot]

Finally, to my question: how do I set up different durations for the two animations (view point and frame)? Currently, they both take 20 seconds, but I wish the viewpoint rotation would be faster, as well as to be running by default; however, my attempts to set `AnimationRunning` as `False` for one variable and `True` for the other did not succeed.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can have only one animation running at the start, but for the viewpoint animation, shouldn't you be able to control that animation's "speed" by varying the frequency in the Sin argument? I.e. using `Sin[2 t]` instead of `Sin[t]` should have the `ViewPoint` oscillate twice as fast, etc.

Comment: Smart remark! Thank you a lot. I still hope it is possible to have different rates though, via some Mathematica instruction

Answer (score 1):

`Animator` basically constructs and `Manipulate`.  `Manipulate` has more flexibility, and it's not much harder to code a simple animation with it than `Animator`.

```
(* some plots to animate *)
g = Table[Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - a y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], {a, 81}];

Manipulate[Labeled[
  Show[g[[i]],
   ViewPoint -> {Sin[t], -2.4 + Sin[t]/2, 2*Sin[t]}],
  s[i], Top],
 {i, 1, 81, 1, Animator,
  AnimationRunning -> False, DefaultDuration -> 20,
  AppearanceElements -> {"ProgressSlider", "PlayPauseButton", 
    "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton"}},
 {t, 0, Pi, Animator,
  AnimationRunning -> False, DefaultDuration -> 32,
  AppearanceElements -> {"ProgressSlider", "PlayPauseButton", 
    "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton"}},
 PreserveImageOptions -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]